# CSS: Rotate3D Ipad glitch

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, ipad

I'm animating the dropdown of my navbar using a `rotateX` transform command. On desktop (every browser) works well, however on **iPad it glitches** (the effect moves the dropdown under the navbar for an instant). When I remove the rotation the object properly displays on every device.
I'm using TailwindCss, but to make debugging simpler I just created a couple of "fictitious" css classes resuming the core CSS classes applied by Tailwind.

Expected result [desktop] (on the left) vs actual behaviour [iPad] (on the right):

[image][image]

```css
.nav{
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 40;
}

.container{
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.button{
  color:white;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown{
  background-color: rgba(35, 43, 50, 0.9);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 14rem;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: perspective(999px) rotateX(-12deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.dropdown-item{
  padding: 1rem;
  --rounded-top:0;
  --rounded-bottom:0;
  border-top-left-radius: var(--rounded-top);
  border-top-right-radius: var(--rounded-top);
  border-bottom-right-radius: var(--rounded-bottom);
  border-bottom-left-radius: var(--rounded-bottom);
}

.dropdown-item:hover{
  background-color: rgba(102, 108, 113, 0.9);
}

.dropdonw-item.first{
  --rounded-top:0.5rem;
}

.dropdonw-item.last{
  --rounded-bottom:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button">
      <p>Button</p>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item first">Item 1</li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">Item 2</li>
        <li class="dropdown-item last">Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Seems like on ipad the menu is under the nav and then moved in front of the nav. Maybe play around with the code to move it to the front sooner. Also, opacity 1 is the same as 100, 1 is opaque and anything less is translucent until you get to 0 which is invisible

Comment: @Huangism fixed opacity. I was translating tailwind classes and I mistakenly wrote 100 instead of 1. The weird thing is that the CSS classes applied both on iPad and on Mac are the same (as you can see there's no media query)

Comment: Yea but with ios devices there is always something different. It looks like the arrow appears about the same time for both except on ipad the menu top part is behind the nav. So whatever brings the menu above, do that first with no transition then animate the rest of the transition. You might need to apply multiple classes or do the animation in js. I don't know reactjs but I have seen many ipad specific weird behaviours

Comment: You know what, maybe just give your .box position relative so you can add a z-index to it, that may solve it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Huangism! I tried relative positioning and it didn't work. I tried also removing completely the arrow, but it still was behind the navbar. By removing the rotation it behaves well also on the iPad. I'm missing something for sure. If I found something working I'll update the post!

Comment: I tried to remove everything, aside from rotation and it still happens. It must be something related to a weird behavior of the stacking context (transform it usually does it).

Comment: Could you edit the code in the question so that it is a simplified version of your menu and shows the problem, I could use my simulator to try and reproduce it then I can play around with it to see if there is a solution to this

Comment: Sorry your box is already absolute, no need to make it relative. It must have something to do with the transform creating a stacking context, if you can put a working example on here, I think someone should be able to get it

Comment: @Huangism I reproduced the behaviour with the smallest amount of code possible. If you run the snippet above on iPad, a part of the dropdown remains under the navbar

Comment: I have tried this on a few different ipad sims with ios 14.4 but could not reproduce the menu behind nav thing. Which ipad and ios are you using?

Comment: iPad Air 4th gen, iPadOS 14.5.1. When I execute the snipped above on my iPad (in an expanded page->Run code snippet and then expand the page) I can reproduce the issue

Comment: I have tried this on iPad air 4th gen, ios 14.2(all I have) Simulator(xcode) and I was not able to see the top of the menu getting cut off. The xcode sim is usually pretty accurate rendering wise compared to real devices. I would suggest you get someone else to try this on different devices/iOS versions. It is possible it is a glitch in that version of iOS.